# How will I be able to run the SERVICE in android

Tags: android, password-protection

I'm developing an application lock in android. I'm trying to use a service to keep my application running in the background but it seems it does not start. I would also like to implement a password screen to the selected applications that the user wants to lock. I have coded some of it:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private ListView list;
    ArrayList<Model> data;
    ApkAdapter adapter;
    private PackageManager packageManager;
    TextView tView;
    ProtectAppProvider pap;
    CheckBox chk;
    ArrayList<String> protectedApps;
    List<PackageInfo> appsList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        packageManager = getPackageManager();
        tView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.appname);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.applist);
        appsList = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
        data = new ArrayList<Model>();

        initialization();
        getApps();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_bar, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        boolean isChecked;
        boolean diditwork = true;
        int getPosition = (Integer) view.getTag();
        Model obj = data.get(getPosition);
        String aName = obj.getAppName();
        String pName = obj.getpName();
        protectedApps = new ArrayList<String>();
        pap = new ProtectAppProvider(getApplicationContext());
        if (((CheckBox) view).isChecked()) {
            try {
                isChecked = true;
                data.get(getPosition).setSelected(isChecked);
                protectedApps.add(aName);
                pap.open();
                pap.createEntry(aName,pName);
                pap.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                diditwork = false;
            } finally {
                if (diditwork)
                    Toast.makeText(this, "LOCKED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                else
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Fail to lock!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        } else {
            isChecked = false;
            data.get(getPosition).setSelected(isChecked);
            diditwork = true;
            try {
                pap.open();
                protectedApps.remove(aName);
                pap.deleteEntry(aName);
                pap.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                diditwork = false;
            } finally {
                if (diditwork)
                    Toast.makeText(this, "UNLOCKED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                else
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Fail to unlock", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
            }
        }

    }
    public void getApps(){
        for (int i = 0; i < appsList.size(); i++) {
            PackageInfo p = appsList.get(i);
            if (packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(p.packageName) != null
                    && ((!p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager())
                            .toString().equals("VoiceAppLock")))) {
                Model model = new Model();
                model.setAppName(p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(
                        getPackageManager()).toString());
                model.setAppIcon(p.applicationInfo
                        .loadIcon((getPackageManager())));
                model.setpName(p.packageName);
                data.add(model);

                Collections.sort(data, Model.AppComparator);

            }
        }
        adapter = new ApkAdapter(MainActivity.this, data, packageManager,
                protectedApps);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    public void initialization(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LockService.class);
        this.startService(intent);  
    }

}
```

LockServices.java

```
public class LockService extends Service {

    private ProtectAppProvider pap;
    private ArrayList<String> protectApps;
    private String appname;
    private static LockService instance;
    private String tag;

    public LockService() {
        this.pap = new ProtectAppProvider(this);
        this.protectApps = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.tag = "LS";
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        updateList();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service Created",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service Destroy",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        Log.i(tag, "Service onStartCommand " + startId);

        final int currentId = startId;

        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 10 * 1000;

                    while (System.currentTimeMillis() < endTime) {
                        synchronized (this) {
                            try {
                                wait(endTime - System.currentTimeMillis());
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    updateList();
                    checkRunningApps();
                    Log.i(tag, "Service running " + currentId);
                }
            }
        };

        Thread t = new Thread(r);
        t.start();
        return Service.START_STICKY;

    }

    public void updateList() {
        appname = "";
        pap.open();
        Cursor c = pap.getPacName();
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                appname = c.getString(0);
                protectApps.add(appname);
            } while (c.moveToNext());

        }
        pap.close();
    }

    public void checkRunningApps() {
        ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService("activity");
        List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> RunningTask = mActivityManager.getRunningTasks(1);
        ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo ar = RunningTask.get(0);
        String activityOnTop=ar.topActivity.getPackageName().toString();

        Log.i("activity on TOp", "" + activityOnTop);

        // Provide the packagename(s) of apps here, you want to show password
        // activity
        if(this.protectApps.contains(activityOnTop)){

            Intent lockIntent = new Intent(LockService.this, Password.class);
            lockIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            LockService.this.startActivity(lockIntent);

        }
    }
}
```

Password.java

```
public class Password extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private EditText userpass;
    private Button submit;
    private Button cancel;
    private String password;
    private int counter;

    public void findView() {
        this.userpass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        this.submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        this.cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        this.password = "12345";
        this.cancel.setOnClickListener(this);
        this.submit.setOnClickListener(this);
        this.counter = 0;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.password);
        findView();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
        findView();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (v.getId() == R.id.button1) {
            String str2 = this.userpass.getText().toString();
            if ((str2 != "") && (str2.equals(this.password))) {
                this.finish();
            } else {
                userpass.setText("");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong Password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                counter++;
                if (counter == 3) {
                    Intent startHomescreen = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                    startHomescreen.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                    startHomescreen.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                    startActivity(startHomescreen);
                }

            }
        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.button2) {
            Intent startHomescreen = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            startHomescreen.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            startHomescreen.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(startHomescreen);
        }

    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.the.voiceapplock"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/applauncher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Password"
            android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:stateNotNeeded="true"
            android:theme="@*android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />

       <service
            android:name="com.the.voiceapplock.services.LockService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" >
        </service>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.the.voiceapplock.services.BootStartUpReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

please kindly help .. thank you :)

Comment: put this line from where you want to start your service startService(new Intent(this, LockServices.class));

Comment: @NadirB it still does not start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `BootStartReceiver` class, try this:

```
public class BootStartReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
            // Start sensor service.
            intent = new Intent(context, LockServices.class);
            context.startService(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

You may also need to declare `BootStartReceiver` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file as follow:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".BootStartReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Well, have you declared `BootStartReceiver` in AndroidManifest.xml file? Update your post with this declaration so I can see what you are doing.

Comment: my application only shows on the cache processes . what should I implement to make it on services in use?

Comment: The `BOOT_COMPLETED` starts your `LockServices` class when the device is restarted. Once your `Service` is started, Android garbage collector may kill your `Service` if the device is running low on memory. If you want a persistent `Service`, you may need to create an alarm via `AlarmManager` to start every few seconds to check if `LockServices` class is running. If it's not, start `LockServices` class again.

Comment: the service already started. but the activity in the service does not. the one that checks for the application being launched by the user. How will I make it work?

Comment: Debug your `if` logic to see if `Password.class` is being executed at all.

Comment: thank you . I made it work but when I open an app, the password class takes a couple of seconds to start. what i should i do to make it start before the app.

Comment: How did you make it work? Can you edit your post so I can see what changes you have made. Thanks.